# How do I drag and drop copy of controls

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, drag

Although I got how to move controls and drag and drop the exisiting control on searching in internet, I didn't get a solution for how to copy a control to a panel/groupbox etc.

I Am developing an application in which I drag and drop buttons from a
 Panel to another Panel. What I need is to drag a button from Panel-1
 and paste a "copy" of it in Panel-2.  Here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own solution.

First of all set the `AllowDrop` property of Panel to true.

```
panel1.AllowDrop=true;
```

Create a `DragEnter` event for Panel from properties window

```
private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

Next, create a `DragDrop` event for Panel from properties window

```
private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     Control c = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as Control;
     // Declare rnd globally for creating random id for dynamic button(eg : Random rnd = new Random();)
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Name = "Button" + rnd.Next(); 
     btn.Size = c.Size;            
     btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(DynamicButton_Click);
     if (c != null)
     {                
         btn.Text = c.Text;
         btn.Location = this.panel1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
         this.panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in way kind of an Object has a protected method called MemberwiseClone which is supposed to do a high level clone of all the members on your object. You can read about it here:

ICloneable Interface: Supports cloning, which creates a new instance of a class with the same value as an existing instance.

The ICloneable interface enables you to provide a customized implementation that creates a copy of an existing object. The ICloneable interface contains one member, the Clone method, which is intended to provide cloning support beyond that supplied by Object.MemberwiseClone. For more information about cloning, deep versus shallow copies, and examples, see the Object.MemberwiseClone method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx

```
public class ControlCloner<T>
{
  public T CloneObject(T sourceObject)
 {
     T newObject = new T();

   // Set properties & events of newObject using reflection... look at the methods available on the Type class.
      return newObject;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Although Drag and drop is working, the original button is getting moved. I actually need the copy of that button to be in Panel 2.

Comment: Ya I have mention about the interface how to create new object(copy of existing object).